# xml parser : parser foundCharacters error

Tags: ios, xml, parsing, rss

I am parsing some rss feeds from a site and when my code reaches the method of parser foundCharacters the application closes with an exc_bad_access error. The strange thing is that when i run my app in the simulator the app runs with no problem. This is my parse code :

```
#pragma mark NSXMLParser delegate

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didEndElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName {

if ([elementName isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

    [item setObject:title forKey:@"title"];
    [item setObject:link forKey:@"link"];

    [feeds addObject:[item copy]];

}

}

- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser didStartElement:(NSString *)elementName namespaceURI:(NSString *)namespaceURI qualifiedName:(NSString *)qName attributes:(NSDictionary *)attributeDict {

element = elementName;

if ([element isEqualToString:@"item"]) {

    item    = [[NSMutableDictionary alloc] init];
    title   = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];
    link    = [[NSMutableString alloc] init];

}

}


- (void)parser:(NSXMLParser *)parser foundCharacters:(NSString *)strings {

if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
    [title appendString:strings];
} else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
    [link appendString:strings];
}

}

- (void)parserDidEndDocument:(NSXMLParser *)parser {

[self.tableView reloadData];
}
```

My error is showing up when it reaches the first line of :

```
if ([element isEqualToString:@"title"]) {
    [title appendString:strings];
} else if ([element isEqualToString:@"link"]) {
    [link appendString:strings];
}
```

When i try to change those lines with for example :

```
[title appendString:strings];
```

it runs perfectly with the main difference that i get no link to enter the rss feed.
In other words the problem seems to be when checking if element is equal to string @"title".
Thank you.

Comment: While there are issues here, I'm not sure why you'd get bad access (unless you're not using ARC). BTW, make sure `didEndElement` sets `element` variable to `nil` At the end of the method (or else you could end up with unintended extra characters in title and link values).

Comment: YES SIR!!! that was it i think. And i can't understand why exactly is this happening. I have set the element variable to nil in didendelement and it works.! no error. Thank you very much for your inspiration.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd certainly expect a bad access if you were not using ARC, in which case a dangling pointer is extremely likely.

Regardless, I would make sure that `didEndElement` sets `element` variable to `nil` at the end of the method (or else you may end up with unintended extra characters in `title` and `link` values). This also minimizes the incidental and unnecessary references to the `elementName` you received in `didStartElement` beyond the point that you actually needed it.

Personally, if I were going to use the `elementName` passed to me in `didStartElement` beyond the scope of that method, I'd be inclined to either `copy` the value passed to me or use some other state variable to keep track of whether I was parsing `title` or `link` or whatever.